# SQL Linked Server Connection Success but simple query returns Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: sql-server-2016, linked-server

I linked a SQL Server in Management Studio and when I test the connection, I do get "the test connection to the linked server succeeded." However, when I try to run a simple query, I get a message

> Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

In my query I am using the linked server `name.database.schema.table`.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Comment: Is it the same user that created the linked server and ran the query? also could you script the linked server definition and add it to your question?